How do you use the "string" function is c
I was watching this CS50 course on computer science and it asked me to add the CS50.h header file but it wasn't available in my vs code as it wasn't cloud based like the cs50 one was
I wasn't really trying much but searching it up on Google led me nowhere

Your question is not very clear, but ill try to help :) If you are missing a header file (one ending in .h) then you might need to download it from CS50. After that you need to write something like #include "CS50.h" at the top of your C file. There might be other things you need to do, but it is difficult to say without more information. Good luck :)

I think you need typedef char *string; but if you can go on with the CS50 without this "string" thing it would be better.

yeah sir thankyou but how do you download the cs50 file

The cs50 "string" is a cs50 thing for use in C, not a standard thing in C. It requires the CS50.h header file. Some associated stuff that is used with it also requires a cs50 library that has to be linked into your program. The header file and library must be a matched pair, as there have been several versions and they need to be consistent. If you are following a course, you would want to use the same version as the course uses and course information should indicate where to get it.

I copied cs50.h and searched in google and it shows me a website -> cs50.h. wow there it is! it wasn't that hard to find you

Just a reminder: After you succeed in using cs50.h you will need to compile and link cs50.c or link with some cs50 library to actually provide the functions you want to use. Does the CS50 material really not cover any preparation of the build environment?

you would want to use the same version as the course uses and course information should indicate where to get it. –
yes but the problem is how to

I was able to get it working as follow:

Download the CS50 library (https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/releases), extract it and open your terminal in this folder
execute sudo make install in this folder
Than you can include the library in your code with #include <cs50.h>
When compiling the program add the -lcs50 flag to link the library


Good job. You have accomplished RTFM (read the fword manual). There is no magic in anything you do that is technical in nature. When faced with a "how do I do X?" or "why is X not working?", you always end up doing the same thing "look it up". If you are working through the CS50 course, understand it isn't a course to teach you how to program. It is a set of problems that exercise what you have already learned. You learn to write C from a good book. Drop by The Definitive C Book Guide and List and Good luck!

The upvote is for mastering step one (RTFM) and as a Welcome to Stack Overflow. The site is easy to use. Research the issue you have (99% of the time you will answer your own question that way). If you still are stuck, then read the About page and also visit the links describing How to Ask a Question and How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example. Providing the necessary details will allow everyone here to help you with your question.
